# Un-Wire an event from being called

Tags: ios, swift

How can I unwire a function so it doesn't get called?

```
//Wire an event
myScrollView.delegate = self
... do something
// How can I unwire it so the scrollview functions dont get called?
```

Comment: Set the `delegate` to `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `delegate` property to `nil` if you no longer wish to have any of the `delegate` methods called.